# Compile latest blender on ubuntu 12.0464bit?

Tags: blender, source

What i want is to compile latest blender from SVN. I am using [this guide](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/Scons) My issues are:

How can i install it with the final .deb created file and how can i give this package to a ppa! So, when i execute

> > sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install subversion build-essential gettext \  libxi-dev libsndfile1-dev \  libpng12-dev libfftw3-dev \ 
> >     libopenexr-dev libopenjpeg-dev \  libopenal-dev libalut-dev
> >     libvorbis-dev \  libglu1-mesa-dev libsdl1.2-dev libfreetype6-dev \ 
> >     libtiff4-dev libavdevice-dev \  libavformat-dev libavutil-dev
> >     libavcodec-dev libjack-dev \  libswscale-dev libx264-dev
> >     libmp3lame-dev python3.2-dev \  libspnav-dev

it gives me this

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libjack-dev :
>   Depends: libjack0 (= 1:0.121.0+svn4538-3ubuntu1) but it is not going
>   to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

I know that skype does not allow the installation of those libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it easier and try:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep blender
```

to install all the packages required to build blender.

Comment: Same thing happens! I cannot install those libraries!

Comment: the only option left is to choose between uninstalling the application that makes the library not available and forcing the installation via `apt-get` with `--force-yes`. There is also another option, using a virtualized environment just for the building process.

Comment: So, what i understand is: Option1-->uninstall skype install dependencies and then force the skype installation   Option2--> build blender in virtual machine and then pass the .deb file on my system. Am i right?thanks

Comment: yes, remember that jack is optional, you can compile blender without jack, the official release of blender it's not linked and does not uses jack.

Comment: Well, i think that a virtualized enviroment for building packages is necessary, So i have to ask is there any way to have a 64bit testing enviroment on 64bit-system , without the vt-x support etc.(virtualbox does not allow to run 64-bit os because my cpu does not support it.Is there any other way)

Comment: Just use Virtualbox or any other solution for virtualized environment, the VT-x extension is sometimes required to make the virtualized envirnoment run faster, but without it you can still run a virtual machine, it will be off-course slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Jack for something in Blender and want to keep Skype (Why wouldn't you), install `jackd libjack-jackd2-dev` which do not conflict with Skype but provide the same functionality. You should be able to enable WITH_JACK in CMake, and it should build, and it should work. It's working for me as I type this, at least.